# cairoDevice produces black images, when used in for loop

Tags: r, ggplot2, cairo

This may be a bug with the cairoDevice package. I'm using this package to generate anti-aliased plots for aesthetic purposes.

The following simplified code DOESN'T work when run as a for loop:

```
for (j in 1:4) {

  Cairo(
    width = 12,
    height = 4,
    file = paste0("Test", j, ".png"),
    surface = "png"
  )

  qplot(1:j)

  dev.off()
}
```

The result of above code is 4 completely black .png images with a 12x4 dimension.

But ran by simply selecting the content of the loop, it works just fine (need to iterate manually by incrementing j by 1 in the console).

It appears that Cairo() simply doesn't like for loops. I tried using Sys.sleep(2) to give extra time for cairo to execute, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why it's not working, but why use Cairo to just produce png files? R already has a `png()` device.

Comment: Hi Michael. As I understand, Cairo offers anti-aliasing which produces aesthetically pleasing plots. I also understand that this is not native yet on Windows R. Am I correct in my understanding?